# Android Studio UI Designer No Title Bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the following `style` to my `Activity` setted in the `Manifest` and it works when I run it. But the UI designer still shows it.

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I'm using the `context` tool but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my root view

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.test.myapp.activity.LoginActivity">
```

I have also selected the `NoActionBar` style in the ui designer upper bar but it still shows it.

Any idea?

Edit: manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.myapp.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.myapp.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
        <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible" >-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you put your manifest?

Comment: I can confirm that this happened to me as well, thought I don't really consider this to be a problem since the final result on the device or the emulator is correct. The Android designer (on either Eclipse ADT or Android Studio) has always been very limited. I'm just glad that the Android Studio's designer is improving a little bit every day. Yesterday for instance, I just noticed that it would render all my custom Views written in Java (as long as I referenced them in the xml). I don't know how long Android Studio had this feature, but I'm quite sure Eclipse ADT never had something like this

Comment: Try `re-building` the project,`syncing project with gradle files` or close Android Studio and open it again.

Comment: how do I sync project with gradle files?

Comment: using the tiny green button in tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml, instead of using:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Solved it for me if it's still relevant for someone.